# Spring, Tomcat @HandleTypes annotation error

Tags: tomcat, maven, spring-mvc

I'm running a relatively simple annotation driven Spring configured web app. I'm using Java 1.6, Tomcat 7 and have I believe the appropriate dependencies in my pom.xml, i.e.  jsp-api:2.2, javax.servlet-api:3.0.1.  I continually get the error below although my webapp doesn't appear to have any problem while running.  I did find one reference to this error online and it suggested adding 'metadata-complete="true"' to my web.xml file which made the @HandleTypes error go away but prevented my app from constructing itself properly.

Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

> Sep 5, 2012 1:29:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig checkHandlesTypes
>   WARNING: Unable to load class [javax.servlet.jsp.el.ImplicitObjectELResolver$ImplicitObjects] to check against the @HandlesTypes annotation of one or more ServletContentInitializers.
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.el.ImplicitObjectELResolver$ImplicitObjects
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:1988)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:1951)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1840)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1808)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1794)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1214)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:828)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:302)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5148)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:842)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1599)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Comment: Make sure that `jsp-api:2.2` and `javax.servlet-api:3.0.1` have `<scope>provided</scope>`.

Comment: That's exactly what was needed.  Do you want to answer it officially and I'll mark it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure that your `war` file doesn't contain Servlet API and JSP API `jar`s, otherwise you'll get tricky classloading problems.

However, you still need them as compile-time dependencies. For this case Maven allows you to declare these dependencies with scope `provided`.

So, make sure that `jsp-api:2.2` and `javax.servlet-api:3.0.1` have `<scope>provided</scope>`.

Comment: If in case not a maven build what is the solution?